# Ktor server clear all cookies of client

Tags: kotlin, cookies, ktor

I have a ktor server and want to clear all cookies from the connecting client.

```kotlin
post("/login") {
            val parameters = call.receiveParameters()
            val username = parameters["username"]
            val password = parameters["password"]

            if (username.isNullOrEmpty() || password.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                call.respondHtmlTemplate(loginTemplate(true), HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                }
            }

            println("Username: $username")
            println("Password: $password")


            // Clear all cookies
            call.response.cookies.clear()
}
```

I tried using `call.response.cookies.clear()` but it didnt work. I got the error message

```
unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public fun kotlin.text.StringBuilder /* = java.lang.StringBuilder */.clear(): kotlin.text.StringBuilder /* = java.lang.StringBuilder */ defined in kotlin.text
```

How do I clear all cookies of a connecting client?

Comment: There is no function `clear()` on cookies.  Set an expiry time, I don't think you can delete cookies.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by clearing cookies?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman deleting all cookies that we Set on the connecting client

Comment: You can iterate all cookies sent by a client and then send them back with a negative expiration date.